# student project allocation and management system

Tags: php

Assuming I have 35 numbers of students with different CGPA and 10 supervisors, how do I match the students to a supervisor equally without giving one supervisor the students with the highest CGPA and others the student with the lowest CGPA? And how can I implement this in PHP.

Comment: have a crack at programming the logic and if/when you get stuck ask again and show the code - no doubt people will be able to assist but alas they'll not write it all for you.

Comment: Try something and maybe we can help you but with no code and no more information we can't do nothing

Comment: This sounds like homework :) Or at least the kind of math homework I recall a few decades ago lol. Send the train car to hit the 5 people!